# Construct a matrix C with components of A,B such that det(C) = det(A)-det(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size (with components $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ respectively), is it possible to form a larger matrix $C$ with components selected from  $\{0,\pm 1,\pm a_{ij}, \pm b_{ij} \}$ such that det(C) = det(A) - det(B) ?

For example, for the boring case of $A$ and $B$ being 1x1 matrices, 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{00} \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} b_{00} \end{bmatrix}, C = \begin{bmatrix} a_{00} & b_{00} \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\det(C) = a_{00} - b_{00} = \det(A) - \det(B)$$

How can we construct $C$ for larger cases like $A,B$ being 2x2, or 3x3?
Is there a general rule to do this for NxN?

If not, can it be proven to be impossible?

Comment: The example is clear, but the general formulation is not.  Besides, the exercise looks devoid of learning value: the determinant's main purpose is to provide a volume form on a manifold.  So, $\det(C) = $ (volume of C(unit cube)), and similarly for $\det(A), \det(B)$.  These unit cubes, the way you have it, are not even in the same dimension.  What is one supposed to learn from this exercise?

Comment: @avs Would the question be more clear if I removed that example? I included it because I was worried it might not be immediately clear what I meant by "components selected from {0,+/-1,+/-a_ij, +/-b_ij}" as I wasn't sure how to word that. But maybe I made things worse. By saying "the general formulation is not [clear]", do you mean the question itself is unclear, or a way to generalize the 1x1 case is not clear? If the later, then I agree, the 1x1 case is likely useless in trying to 'extrapolate' from.

Comment: None of the following is clear: "the components selected" (e.g., which components would one select if A and B were 3 by 3?), the question itself, and, most importantly, what this mathematics (a linear combination of volumes in different dimensions) is supposed to model.  The last of these is, to me, the most important.  Once the goals are clear, the modeling becomes meaningful.

Comment: @avs It means each component of C must be one element from the set {0,+1,-1,+a_00,-a_00,+a_01,-a_01,...,+b_00,-b_00,...}. I don't understand why you ask which components we would use for a 3x3. The whole point of the question is asking how we would construct C. Det(C) = Det(A) - Det(B) is relating three scalars. If you want to imagine A and B to be of the same dimension as C for your analysis, then just consider larger versions of A and B by putting them in a block diagonal with the identity as that doesn't change the determinant.

Comment: Viewing the determinant of a matrix as a function in terms of its components, results in a function with many interesting computational properties. For instance, expanding out the function would result in an exponential number of terms, but due to properties of the determinant, a polynomial defined by a determinant can be evaluated in sub-exponential time ~ O(n^3).  If I have two such polynomials which are represented as determinants, I am interested in what operations I can perform (subtraction here) and rewrite the result as a new determinant just using components of the original matrices.

Comment: Regardless of how I got here, this is a mathematical puzzle which I'm curious about for its own sake now. Use whatever tools or viewpoint you desire to approach it. But if a tool doesn't seem to fit, the question stands all the same.